# Playing audio files using mediaPlayer library in android programming (kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, android-mediaplayer

i am implementing an android app in kotlin that plays audio through audio files using mediaPlayer library . Everything work well but when an audio is playing , when clicked , the  second audio is playing simultaneously with the first . How could i solve it ? here is the code :

```
     when(language){
    "french"->{
    play_audio(1)
    }
    
    "english"->{
    play_audio(2)
    }
else->{
   //Unavailable language
}
    }
```

//

Here is the audio_play function :

```
     private fun play_audio(code:Int){
            if(code==1){
                if(mediaPlayer==null){
                    mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,R.raw.french)
                    mediaPlayer?.start()
                    last_code=1
          
                }else{
                        if(code==last_code){
                            mediaPlayer?.release()
                            mediaPlayer=null
                    
                        }else{
                           
                            mediaPlayer?.release()
                            mediaPlayer = null
                            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.french)
                            mediaPlayer?.start()    
                        }
                }
            }else if(code== 2){

                if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.english)
                    mediaPlayer?.start()
                    last_code = 2
                  
                } else {

                    if (code == last_code) {
                            mediaPlayer!!.release()
                            mediaPlayer = null
                          
                        } else {

                        Log.d("TAG", "stop and playing track 2")

                        mediaPlayer?.stop()
                        mediaPlayer!!.release()
                        mediaPlayer = null
                        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.english)
                        mediaPlayer?.start()
              }
 }
        }
```